# og:image tag is not showing any constructed value

Tags: facebook

Am I making any mistake in raw tags for image ? Rest all tag works except image. I have even tried to provide image url with different domain, different size and different types but none constructed on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

[image]

Comment: Can you share the actual URL, please? (Image is not working at the moment, seems the service is temporarily down.)

Comment: @CBroe Yes, you were right. Looks like service was down. Everything is back to normal now. I actually thought of service down and tried to search net and facebook dashboard, but didn't found anything useful, therefore as a last resort I have put on stackoverflow. Thanks a lot for your response.